ImportError: DDL load failed while importing _cext: %1 is not a valid Win32 application ->when trying to import Matplotlib
I know this question has been asked in similar capacities, and the main cause is always determined to be the cause of mixing 32-bit with 64-bit.
BUT...I have no idea how that could be the case this time!
I have a 32-bit windows 10 installed, with only 1 python version (3.8 32-bit) installed.
I checked what packages I needed, and what is the latest compatible version they have and only installed those:
enter image description here
When I run my application however, I get the following error:
enter image description here
I even checked the installation location of kiwisolver which raised the error:
enter image description here
I didn't see any issue there, except for the weird .pyi extension, but that is how it was for any version I installed, and nothing changed when I replaced it from a 64bit install, or changed the extension.
I checked every install used a whl for 32bit installs. I am at a loss.
And yes, everything works on a 64-bit version with the same packages installed, and my application works correctly, however we still use 32-bit systems where this application will be necessary.
